# Как вводить данные через пробел

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

В первой строчке программы мы получаем количество людей, далее, во второй строчке, мы должны ввести ответы этих людей(0 или 1). Пример:

> Вводим в первой строчке: 3
>
> Во второй строчке вводим: 1 1 0

Как это сделать? Обязательно, чтобы ввод данных осуществлялся в 2 две строки.

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле необязательно знать количество людей, чтобы осуществить ввод ваших данных. Но если делать все по Вашему образцу, то:
`People = input("Количество людей: ")

Data = list(map(int,input("Данные: ").split())) # Если мы хотим сохранить данные в виде списка`